# Overcame php math limitations likethe fractional part

Tags: php, math, mathematical-optimization

So how do you guys do math in php to be sure that you get the right anwser? Because as we know  when typecasting php truncates away the fractional part(*.99999) so we won't get a right answer, eg:

```
print ((0.1+0.7) * 10) //8
print (int) ((0.1+0.7) * 10) //7
```

A solution will be:

```
print (int) round(((0.1+0.7) * 10)) //8
```

But I don't know if it's the best solution, I'm asking this because now these days when using noSQL or other things most of the time we will need to typecast our data, so what do you guys do to overcame these situations?

Comment: Again, [float precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Good lord, that `0.1` and `0.7` are taken from manual, aren't them?

Comment: Yes sir, that's correct

Comment: PHP Manual says.. `So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are available.`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question imposes that it's PHP's fault when dealing with float values. It is not. The problems you are experiencing are everywhere where float mathematics is in place, in any language.

Some programming languages for financial calculations offer a special value type "money" or "decimal" which guarantees floating point correctness. The only equivalent PHP has to offer is the "arbitrary precision mathematics" module: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Note that this has some implications in regards to storage used for each value, performance, and how to transfer the values to somewhere else.

Usually, you get along with the floating point values imprecisions quite good, though.